# Getting the file browser twice

Tags: jquery

I have a little application which can be found here: [templater.pmueller.dev.xiag.ch/frontend/show/id/3/authkey/789](http://templater.pmueller.dev.xiag.ch/frontend/show/id/3/authkey/789) If the site is down, try again in an hour. They are experiencing problems atm. Also everything is quite beta and it's my first bigger jQuery project.

If you drag an element from the left to the right, you can double click on the left handed little images as well as on the text.

My problem is that if i double click on the images, the code gets called twice. If you don't experience this, reload the page. Normally, a newly added element doesn't show this problem, but as soon as you reload, the bug is there.

My guess is some messed up event handlers, but I'm too new for debugging that correctly.

Here are some code snippets:

jquery.InlineEditor.js

```
   $(this).on("dblclick", '.editor-img', function() {
       if($(this).is('img')) {
           $("#imgUpload").attr('action', '/frontend/upload/width/' + $(this).width() + '/height/' + $(this).height());
           $('#imageInput').click();
           $('body').data('clickedElement', this);
       }
   });
```

I also thought of just unbind the event before i bind it again, but I really want to know what to do and how a nice solution to this problem looks like.

Thanks

Comment: Hmm... unstable site behind a link obfuscator. No thanks.

Comment: I'm no hacker, cracker, thief or whatevery you are thinking. Over there  the provides just has some problems with the connection. And sorry for using a short link...Check my other posts i always used short links.

Answer (score 0):

Got it solved.

I've applied the plugin like that:

```
$("#editor table").applyEditor();
```

And since i got nested tables on 2 levels, on was attached twice.

Doing `$("#editor > table").applyEditor();` or even just `$("#editor").applyEditor();` does work perfectly.